# Error: not enough storage is available to process this command when install window server 2003 in win 7 32 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2003

My computer has 25 G NTFS free for window server 2003 sp2.
When I run install file : WindowsServer2003-KB914961-SP2-x86-ENU.exe, The system returns error message as the title after extract files completed.
I tried solving follow :http://support.microsoft.com/kb/106167 but not sucessful with the same message.

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently you need to tell Windows that you want to use the machine
>   as a file server and that it should allocate resources accordingly. 
>   Set the following registry key to ‘1′:
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory
>   Management\LargeSystemCache and set the following registry key to ‘3′:
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6573c5f7-7c61-4c4d-bd04-0f55518ecbeb/win-7-pro-x64-error-0x8007046a-not-enough-server-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command?forum=w7itpronetworking)

Also, try https://serverfault.com/questions/147526/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command

Comment: I tried as you said but not successful.